# Testing Echarts react component with jest, EchartElement is null

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, echarts

Doing a snapchot test of a component with several nested children components, one which holds a Echart (bar-chart). When rendering in browser, EchartElement is set to the chart dom element:

```
 <div class="echarts-for-react " _echarts_instance_="ec_1551342959315" size-sensor-id="1" style="height: 360px; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; user-select: none; position: relative; background: transparent;">
...
</div>
```

But running the test, its null, which makes the test fail. Do I need to mock this somehow? Doesn't sound right...All the properties it is expecting are passed in correctly also in test mode...I checked...

Is there some configuration/setup I need to make Echarts work with Jest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that my first answer didn't work for me at the end... I kept running the test and fixing whatever it was complaining about, but there was always something else...

So with some help from a colleague, the solution was to stop React Echarts to call Echarts by mocking the function triggering the rendering.

```
let spy: any

beforeAll(() => {
    spy = jest.spyOn(echarts, 'getInstanceByDom').mockImplementation(() => {
        return {
            hideLoading: jest.fn(),
            setOption: jest.fn(),
            showLoading: jest.fn()
        }
    })
})
afterAll(() => {
    spy.mockRestore()
})
it('Renders show correctly', () => {
    const tree = renderer
        .create(
            <Show />
        )
        .toJSON()
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

In our case we were not interested in actually testing the canvas rendering part, so that worked for us.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I had to mock the ref object:

```
function createNodeMock(element: any) {
    return {
        getSomething: jest.fn(() => 'pizza'),
        setSomething: jest.fn(),
        property: null,
    }
}
it('Renders show correctly', () => {
    const options = { createNodeMock }
    const tree = renderer
        .create(
            <Show/>,
            options
        )
        .toJSON()
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

Every time I ran into an error running the test, I went to where the method or property was called, console logged, looked what the value was while in the browser and set the data in the mockData. Maybe there is a better way of doing this, but it got it done...